# Jquery do not recognize the function I called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a Javascript function that I referenced in the View but I am getting an error that the function is not 'function'

I have tried to call and renaming it but I have not succeeded.

Here is the function that is in the external JS file

```
$.fn.onlyNumb = (function () {

        $(this).on('keypress', function () {
            try {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (isNaN(val)) {
                    val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
                    if (val.split('.').length > 2)
                        val = val.replace(/\.+$/, "");
                }
                $(this).val(val); 
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err.Description);
            }
        });

    });
```

This is How I referenced the JS and called the function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/MyCustomScripts.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".payslip").each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).onlyNumb();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I expect that the error should not be there because I referenced the external jS file well and called the function as expected.

Comment: Have you included jquery library in html document ?

Comment: @user2932057 yes like this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have tried its working fine.. Can you please check whether `MyCustomScripts.js` is referred properly ?

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools network panel and see if there are any errors. It's likely you have a 404 on MyCustomScripts.js.

Comment: Browsers probably won't support the `~/Scripts` syntax shells do for referring to something in your home directory, and the script does not get loaded.

Comment: @AKX so what is the best way to reference?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the $(document).ready({function()})
as below and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/MyCustomScripts.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(".payslip").each(function (i, obj) {
            $(this).onlyNumb();
        });

</script>
```